# How to Find EBS Volume ID of Drive in Windows on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

We have several EC2 instances, all with several drives. It becomes confusing to monitor which drive is the correct one in the AWS console when there are many drives together.

Naming convention can help this to an extent.

But is there a way to obtain the volume id (or some identifier) in windows of an EBS disk so that it can be found in the AWS console?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AWS Tools for Powershell](http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) to query for all volumes attached a given instance. Here's an example:

```
# Specify your instance's ID
$instance = "i-1234abcd"

# Get a collection of all volumes attached to the instance
$volumes = @(get-ec2volume) | ? { $_.Attachments.InstanceId -eq $instance}

# Get a collection of each volume's ID property
$volumeNames = $volumes | % { $_.VolumeId}
```

This will invoke the [Get-EC2Volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Volume.html) cmdlet, and returns a [Amazon.EC2.Model.Volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2Volume_NET3_5.html) object for each volume that is attached to the running instance.  From there, you can extract the volume names as above.

If you are running this from the EC2 instance itself, try pulling the instance ID from the EC2 web service instead:

```
# Get Instance ID from the EC2 metadata web service
$instanceID = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using below script. This script will iterate over all the EBS volumes and add a tag to EBS according to its Disk label. 
You can modify it, as per your need (refer bottom if-else blocks).
Your EC2 needed the proper EC2 Write IAM role.

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\cfn\log\Tag-EBS-Volumes.ps1.txt -Append
        # Create a hash table that maps each device to a SCSI target
        $Map = @{"0" = '/dev/sda1'}
        for($x = 1; $x -le 25; $x++) {$Map.add($x.ToString(), [String]::Format("/dev/xvd{0}",[char](97 + $x)))}
        for($x = 78; $x -le 102; $x++) {$Map.add($x.ToString(), [String]::Format("/dev/xvdc{0}",[char](19 + $x)))}

    Try {
        # Use the metadata service to discover which instance the script is running on
        $InstanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest '169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').Content
        $AvailabilityZone = (Invoke-WebRequest '169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone').Content
        $Region = $AvailabilityZone.Substring(0, $AvailabilityZone.Length -1)

        # Get the list of volumes attached to this instance
        $BlockDeviceMappings = (Get-EC2Instance -Region $Region -Instance $InstanceId).Instances.BlockDeviceMappings
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "Could not access the AWS API, are your credentials loaded?"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | %{
        $Drive = $_
        # Find the partitions for this drive
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |  Where-Object {$_.Antecedent -eq $Drive.Path.Path} | %{
            $D2P = $_
            # Get details about each partition
            $Partition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition |  Where-Object {$_.Path.Path -eq $D2P.Dependent}
            # Find the drive that this partition is linked to
            $Disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition | Where-Object {$_.Antecedent -in $D2P.Dependent} | %{
                $L2P = $_
                # Get the drive letter for this partition, if there is one
                Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.Path.Path -in $L2P.Dependent}
            }

            $BlockDeviceMapping = $BlockDeviceMappings | Where-Object { $_.DeviceName -eq $Map[$Drive.SCSITargetId.ToString()] }

             If( $Disk.VolumeName -eq "") {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-Root"
             }  ElseIf ($Disk.VolumeName -eq "ABC" )
             {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-ABC"
             }ElseIf ($Disk.VolumeName -eq "DEF" )
             {
                $tagvalue= "$env:COMPUTERNAME-DEF"
             }Else
             {
                $tagvalue= ""
             }

             New-EC2Tag -Resources $BlockDeviceMapping.Ebs.VolumeId -Tags @{ Key = "Name"; Value = $tagvalue } # Add volume name tag that matches VolumeId
        }
    }
```